# How do I get lining figures when using Latin modern with the cfr-lm package?

Tags: oldstylenums, latin-modern

When using the `cfr-lm` package with the Latin modern font (`lmodern` package) I get text figures as standard. This is good, but sometimes I want to explicitly use lining figures. How can this be achieved?

```
% !tex program = pdflatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}

123 % (Produces text figures)

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'lining' figures? Aligning them to the text line, left/right justified?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/oldstylenums/info and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures

Answer (score 3):

As per the manual, loading the package without options is equivalent to:

```
\usepackage[%
   rm={oldstyle=true,proportional=true},%
   sf={oldstyle=true,proportional=true},%
   tt={oldstyle=true,proportional=true,variable=true},%
   qt=false%
]{cfr-lm}
```

Hence by default, you are supposed to get `oldstyle` digits. You can easily change them.

You can use `rm={lining=true}` or `rm={oldstyle=false}` option.

```
% !tex program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rm={lining=true}]{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}

123 % (Produces text figures)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If one wants to specify some particular place where lining figures should be used one can also use `\textl{123}`:

```
% !tex program = pdflatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}

123 % (Produces text figures)

\textl{123} % (Produces lining figures)

\end{document}
```